# How to check a asset file is YAML or Binary format? And am I switch it's format directly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, yaml

For some reason , I need edit `xxx.preafb` file , But Unity `.prefab` file have two format , binary or YAML
So How can I detect `xxx.prefab` is a `YAML` format or `binary`. And If I Detect this file is format by binary, How Can I switch that to `YAML`.
I Know Editor > AssetSerialization > Mode it can format all asset of project , But it too much change...

Comment: How about distinguish using prefab that serialized by YAML format, when you open 'YAML' file, it has header something like '%YAML 1.1' so if "*.prefab" file doesn't have yaml header then you can take it binary otherwise it would be YAML file

Comment: So when you read first line of prefab and that contains '%YAML x.x' then it would be YAML format otherwise binary

Comment: @BrianChoi good idea!

Answer (score 1):

By @BrainChoi suggest , Just check first line solution.

```
 static bool IsYAML(string path)
    {
        if(!File.Exists(path))
        {
            return false;
        }

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            if (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                string header = sr.ReadLine();
                return header.Contains("%YAML 1.1");
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this might fail if there is e.g. a trailing `\n` or `\r\n` ... maybe you should use `return header.Contains("%YAML 1.1");` instead or even `var match = Regex.Match(header, "^%YAML \d\.\d"); return match.Success;` or something like that